# How to check whether primary tab record is opened in edit mode or not in salesforce service console

Tags: service-cloud-console

I have a requirement in which I should check from my sidebar VF page whether the enclosing primary tab is opened in edit mode or not. How can I check that?

Here the primary tab edit page is a VF page. I could see the URL for Edit and detail page the same in salesforce service console.

If the primary tab opened in edit mode I want to do some operation in the sidebar VF page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the event handling mechanisms in the console toolkit to do this. Since your edit page is a VF page you could use the toolkit fire a custom event like this when the edit page loads (alternatively, use a custom JS button to replace your Edit button on the detail page and fire this event from there)

```
sforce.console.fireEvent( 'MyCustomEditEvent', 'Some event message you send', (optional)callback:Function );
```

Then in your sidebar you have a listener like this

```
sforce.console.addEventListener( 'MyCustomEditEvent', eventListener:Function)
```

Then the eventListener function you specify does whatever handling you want the sidebar to do.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_fireevent.htm